# Unable to display images in FTL template (Java, FreeMaker, Vaadin)

Tags: java, image, vaadin

I can't display images in FTL template (FreeMaker tool). Images are loading from web content, but I can't load it from app resources. In my app I use Vaadin, Spring Framework and FreeMaker. How to fix this problem? Thanks for reply.

login.ftl: http://pastebin.com/N1VX30Zr[1](http://pastebin.com/NtZD5zSY)

servlet-context.xml: http://pastebin.com/1SFSwmJT[1](http://pastebin.com/NtZD5zSY)

web.xml: http://pastebin.com/NtZD5zSY[1](http://pastebin.com/NtZD5zSY)

LoginController.java:

```
package pl.controlprocess.flota.web;

import com.vaadin.server.ThemeResource;
import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
public class LoginController implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String login(HttpServletRequest request, @RequestParam(value = "error", defaultValue = "false", required = false)Boolean isError, ModelMap model)
{       
    if (isError)
    {
        model.put("isError", isError);
    }

    model.put("app_ctx", request.getContextPath());

    return "login";
}
```

Comment: Have a look at the generated output from FTL and print the value app_ctx.

Comment: app_ctx: /cpauto and generated output from FTL: http://pastebin.com/HnneGx2B

Comment: See if you can access /cpauto/CAM00127.jpg . Put this after end of ur current url.

Comment: Yes, I put this image into this folder, but when I run app in browser it (image) doesn't appear. When I insert full address to the address bar in web browser (http://localhost:8080/cpauto/CAM00127.jpg) then browser redirect me to the http://localhost:8080/cpauto/login context and don't display this image.

Comment: This css code display image: background:url('http://s21.postimg.org/efzvsih2d/CAM00127.jpg') but this code don't when I put app resources path: <img src="${app_ctx}/CAM00127.jpg" />

Comment: My Spring Framework security.xml file: http://pastebin.com/kkEVGfGB

Answer (score 0):

This is too complex a configuration to quickly scan over - but I believe the problem is that you've configured the Vaadin Servlet to pick up all requests to the root of the context (servlet mapping to /*).

Vaadin will only serve static resources from underneath the VAADIN/ subdirectory (and even then, it's more complicated than that - you'd need to put images in a directory related to the theme that your Vaadin app is using).

I note, though, that someone has already thought of this, as they've created a mapping for /static/ to the default servlet.

If you add the images to the "static" subdirectory of the root of the webapplication, and then change the references in the template to be `${app_ctx}/static/CAM00127.jpg`, you should be fine.